# Smallest multiplier to make a rational number whole

Tags: number-theory

This might be a really stupid question. For a given rational number q, is there a simple way of finding the smallest natural number n such that qn is a natural number?

Comment: Write $q$ as $\frac ab$ with $a$ and $b$ coprime integers. Then $b$ is the number you're after.

Comment: Do you count $0$ as a natural number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the denominator when the rational number has been put into lowest terms.  A rational number $a/b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.  Can be put into lowest terms by means of [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Consider $\dfrac{1989}{867}$. You need $\gcd(1989,867)$, the **greatest common divisor** of $1989$, and $867$.

The divisors of $867$ are given in this table:
\begin{align}
& 1 \times 867 \\
& 3 \times 289 \\
& 17 \times 51 
\end{align}
They are $1,3,17,51,289,867$.

The divisors of $1989$ are found here:
\begin{align}
& 1\times 1989 \\
& 3\times 663 \\
& 9\times 221 \\
& 13 \times 153 \\
& 17 \times 117 \\
& 39 \times 51
\end{align}
They are $1,2,9,13,17,39,51,117,153,221,663,1989$.

The **common divisors** of $1989$ and $867$ are the numbers these two lists have in **common**:
$$
1,\ 3,\ 17,\ 51.
$$
The **greatest** of these is $51$.  So $\gcd(1989,867) = 51$.

Hence we have $\dfrac{1989}{867} = \dfrac{51\times39}{51\times17} = \dfrac{39}{17}$.

That is in lowest terms.

The smallest integer by which this can be multiplied to get an integer is the denominator when it is in lowest terms, i.e. it is $17$.

Here is how Euclid's algorithm efficiently finds the greatest common divisor ($\gcd$):

\begin{align}
& \gcd(1989,867) \\
= {} & \gcd(255,867) & & \text{since 255 is the remainder when 1989 is divided by 867} \\
= {} & \gcd(255,102) & & \text{since 102 is the remainder when 867 is divided by 255} \\
= {} & \gcd(51,102) & & \text{since 51 is the remainder when 255 is divided by 102} \\
= {} & \gcd(51,0) & & \text{since 0 is the remainder when 102 is divided by 51} \\
= {} & 51.
\end{align}

As far as anybody today knows, Euclid was the first to write about this algorithm.  That tells you it's about 23 centuries old.  It is the oldest algorithm still in widespread use.

Comment: You had a 9 instead of a 0 in the last "since". I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Write $q = a/b$ "in lowest terms"—i.e. so that $a$ and $b$ have no common factors. (If you are given $q$ as $a/b$ but $a$ and $b$ have a common factor, divide them both by this factor.) Then the number you seek is simply $b$.

Comment: Yes, I just worked it out. It's basically b / gcd(a,b). Is there a formula that just involves q, as opposed to a and b?

Comment: The reason I'm thinking about this is the following: if someone says a survey result was x%, is there a simple formula for the fewest number of people that could have been involved in the survey?

Comment: The function you're looking for is related to Thomae's function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function. (Specifically, you're looking for $1/f(x)$, where $f$ is Thomae's function.) As Thomae's function is continuous at all irrational numbers and discontinuous at all rational numbers, it's not going to be generated by any sort of simple algebraic expression in $q$.

Comment: @Tom: that's a more complicated (and interesting!) question because most people who say that sort of thing are rounding. E.g. 67% could mean two out of three.

Comment: @TomOffer : Do you know Euclid's algorithm?  See my answer. ${}\qquad{}$